# Thread NullPointerException if ran outside netbeans

Tags: java

I create an object which gets the image from a package, to then draw it on the screen later on. When I run the code in netbeans, it works fine. Outside of netbeans I get a null pointer exception error.
Here's my code. I used the println part to see if "frog" is equal to null. When ran is says it is equal to  "/images/upFrogStill.png" so i'm unsure why the null pointer exception.
The error is on the "ImageIcon ii..." line.

```
public class Frog extends Sprite implements Commons {

String frog = "/images/upFrogStill.png";

 public Frog() {
 System.out.println("frog = " + frog);
        ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(frog));
        image = ii.getImage();
        width = image.getWidth(null);
        height = image.getHeight(null);
        resetState();

}
  void resetState() {
     if(frog != null){
     frog = "/images/upFrogStill.png";
    x = 185;
    y = 397;
}}
}
```

Comment: Make sure the resource is on your classpath at `/images/upFrogStill.png`. How do you run the application outside netbeans?

Comment: Based on the code, it looks like `frog` might be set by some other package level class. If this is true, you should define a constant instead of having two different inline strings that define the path. If this is not the case, you should make `frog` final and then you don't need the `null` check.

Comment: The image file is in a netbeans package "images" and is found and works fine in netbeans. I can't make frog final either as it gets changed to different file paths later in the game to animate the frog.

Comment: I run it as a jar file. To find the error I ran the jar in cmd prompt as it didn't even open up a window.

Answer (score 4):

There is a high possiblilty that

`ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(frog));` is returning [null](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) since **it cannot find the resource.**

If you are running outside netbeans, make sure you **Include the file in your classpath**.

> `ClassLoader.getResource is "absolute";`
>
> Class.getResource is relative to the package of the class unless you
>    prefix it with a '/'.

Hope this helps.